# Copy arrays from different location in a worksheet and use it to paste it into any other application without additional spaces

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My excel sheet creates three proper sentences at three different locations in the worksheet based on the data in the tables but has double spaces between some of the words. I am trying to find a code where I can click a button that copies information from these different arrays in the worksheet that I can then paste into a word file without any double spaces or tab spaces and add some additional generic lines.

Currently, we are manually copying information from these arrays into a notepad to remove the table, the cells and their formating. Then manually replace all the double space and tab spaces with a single space, add some additional generic lines and then copying this information into a Word file.

Trying to write a code that will allow me to do this by clicking the button and then pasting it anywhere I want. What code can I use for this? Thanks.

Comment: DOn't make life hard for yourself.  Paste into Word then use word find/replace over the pasted range to replace the unwanted characters with single spaces.

Comment: I will use the trim and clean function in excel to clean the data but can you help me with a code that I can use to copy the three sets of arrays into the clipboard with a single click which I can then paste anywhere using CTRL + V as simple text without any formating but the arrays need to be one below the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas, untested so you will probably have to experiment to get them to work.  If you get stuck, please use google to research the problem, then post your code and issue in a new question, so folk have more to go on. I'm assuming you have found the VBA editor, the alt-f11 shortcut may work.

1. Use the Names Manager to designate each of the three sentence locations as a "named range", e.g. first_sentence, second_sentence and third_sentence
2. Choose a shape and add it to your workbook. The shape will serve as the button. If you right click on the shape, at the bottom of the list of options, is one to connect a macro (which does not exist yet)
3. In the VBA code editor, make a new module, then create the macro by typing what is below. After creating it, you can connect it to your button, and that will allow you to test it.

```
Option explicit
' the macro "transfer_text" controls the export of text from the Excel sheet to the Word document

sub transfer_text()
' this is where clean-up code and everything goes

end sub
```

4. You need to tell your transfer_text macro where the cells of interest are, perhaps by pasting the following into the body of the macro:

```
dim range_first as range, range_second as range, range_third as range, clean_first as string, clean_second as string, clean_third as string
' set the ranges so the macro knows where the data is  
  with thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")
    set range_first = .range("first_sentence")
    set range_second = .range("second_sentence")
    set range_third = .range("third_sentence")
  end with

' update the data (without changing the original) using the clean_text function (see below)
  clean_first = clean_text(range_first)
  clean_second = clean_text(range_second)
  clean_third = clean_text(range_third)

' this is where we connect Word
```

I would use a function to clean the text in each of the ranges, like this, stored outside the main macro, though in the same module for convenience.  You can add text editing operations to it later:

```
Function clean_text(string_text as string) as string
' the text from the range is passed in
' various operations performed on the text
' the result is sent back to where the function was called

clean_text = trim(string_text)

end function
```

That is rather alot already, and we have not even connected to Word. To connect to Word is really better done as a separate topic. You will need to set a specific reference to word, using the Tools-References menu in the VBA project. Scroll down the list until you find Microsoft Word, and tick the box.

That will give you access to the object library for Word, so you can place your text using bookmarks in the Word document.

You will also need to deal with the file object - opening the Word document.  Another topic for you to research!

That should get you started!

Some notes on debugging.  Set a breakpoint at the start of the With statement by clicking the mouse in the left hand margin of the code editor. Then click you button... the code will stop at the breakpoint. Use the mouse-over and the Immediate Window (you may need to unhide it) to check variable values. Press F8 to step forward one line of code. In the Immediate Window, type a ? followed by the variable you want to check.